# SSL secured website pulling content from third party web service - we need to use SSL on both

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Lets say we have an SSL secured domain - https://xyz.com and we are pulling content from a third party service.  They are set up on service.xyz.com (unsecured)

As a result the page is an issue due to PII concerns.

Obviously, the two urls are on completely different IP addresses.  I'm new at working with SSL and not quite sure how to approach this.  Should we use two certificates here or is it possible to configure one cert to encompass both IPs?

Answer (score 0):

You can either buy two certificates or get one with multiple domains included in the validation.  The latter are called SAN (or subjectAlternativeName) certificates.  You can buy these certificates from many CAs.

Given that you state that service.xyz.com is a third party service (...that you control the webserver for?), it would generally be considered best practice to obtain two certificates for the two sites, rather than having one certificate (with a single private key).

Comment: We control the domain name for service.xyz.com, however the service is hosted through a third party's servers.  They have stated that they can provide a static IP for our use in this regard.  I am essentially trying to figure out how the SSL will work.  Particularly because the content from the web service is displayed through an iFrame.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to have them set up the static IP and then use that IP for an SSL vhost on their end.  Then you can consume the service via https://service.xyz.com inside the iframe and you will not receive any mixed content warnings.  I would definitely suggest two separate certificates for this situation, not a SAN.